# I want to specify the location of a store in Paris using ggmap, but it doesn't come out well

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

The map doesn't show Paris, shows another country, or shows an error..
register_google key is mine, so I hide it.

```
library(ggmap)
register_google(key = "...")
```

```
dt <- read.csv("sfdff.csv", header=T)
```

```
a <- c(mean(dt$lon),mean(dt$lat))
paris <- get_map(a, zoom=7, 
                 scale = 2, size = c(640,640),
                 maptype="roadmap")

ggmap(paris) + 
  geom_point(data=dt, 
             aes(x=lon,y=lat), 
             size=2, col = "black",
             alpha=0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is using the `osmdata` package and `getbb` function to provide a bbox object. In this you don't need a google API key. You can use the following code:

```
library(ggmap)
pacman::p_load(ggmap, osmdata)
map <- get_map(location = getbb("paris"), source = "stamen")
ggmap(map)
```

Output:

[image]

Now you can add your data points to the `ggmap` of Paris.